# Spark On windows gives error in saveAsTextFile

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I have installed Spark on my laptop and I am trying to execute some very basic commands. Most of them work except .saveAsTextFile. In pyshell I wrote

```
nums=sc.parallellize([1,2,3])
nums.saveAsTextFile("file:///C:/Java/ouput")
```

The last statement of saveAsTextFile gives me the following error

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 8) 
    / 8]2018-03-24 11:48:14 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 6.0 in stage 
        0.0 (TID 6)
ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741701:
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    2018-03-24 11:48:14 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741701:
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    2018-03-24 11:48:14 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 6 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
    2018-03-24 11:48:14 ERROR SparkHadoopWriter:91 - Aborting job job_20180324114813_0003.
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741701:
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    Driver stacktrace:
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
            at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
            at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2080)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1067)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:957)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1493)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1472)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1472)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1472)
            at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:550)
            at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741701:
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            ... 1 more
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1568, in saveAsTextFile
        keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path)
      File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
      File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o39.saveAsTextFile.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:96)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1067)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:957)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1493)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1472)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1472)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1472)
            at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:550)
            at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741701:
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    Driver stacktrace:
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
            at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
            at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2080)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            ... 41 more
```

The error message was too long and mostly repetitive so I posted most of the it but couldn't include the last part due to size constraint.
This seems very basic and still somehow doesn't work. I am not sure what I might be doing wrong. Most of the suggestions that I have found until now have not worked for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the output path seems wrong. try `nums.saveAsTextFile("file:///C:\\Java\\ouput")`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan That gives a similar error too. Have you tried to save file in Spark on windows without Hadoop? Have you been successful?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set *winutils.exe* correctly?
Set the `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable correctly and make sure that *winutils.exe* can execute. If it can't, you may need to download *MSVC Runtime Library*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should write to HDFS (Hadoop File System) as default.

I have simulated a session on a single cluster node. Here is the full list of commands creating the list, writing it to HDFS and finally printing out the results on the console using `hdfs`:

```
spark-shell
```

After the shell has started you type:

```
val nums = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5))
nums.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/simple_list")
:quit
```

Now we read the data from HDFS (Hadoop File System):

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/simple_list
```

This prints something like:

```
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1 gil_fernandes hadoop          0 2018-03-24 16:39 /tmp/simple_list/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 gil_fernandes hadoop          4 2018-03-24 16:39 /tmp/simple_list/part-00000
-rw-r--r--   1 gil_fernandes hadoop          6 2018-03-24 16:39 /tmp/simple_list/part-00001
```

Finally you print out the content of the files using `hdfs` again:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /tmp/simple_list/part-*
```

This prints out:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

You can also use the `hdfs dfs cat` command to get the file from HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /tmp/simple_list/part-* > simple_list.txt
```

**Update**

If you want to run `saveAsTextFile` using the `file://` protocol you should typically run `spark-shell` under the user which runs you Spark cluster.

These are the steps I have used to save as a text file on the local file system:

Bash:

```
sudo -i
su - yarn
spark-shell
```

Spark-shell:

```
val nums = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5))
nums.saveAsTextFile("file:///tmp/simple_list_12")
:quit
```

Bash:

```
ls /tmp/simple_list_12
```

Output of the last command:

```
part-00000  part-00001  _SUCCESS
```

Comment: So basically you are saying that we cannot saveAsTextFile if we do not have Hadoop set up? From what I understand is that, Spark runs even without Hadoop setup. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: No, you can save using different protocols, like file:// and gcs://, but the default one saves on HDFS and this is the least problematic one too. In order for saveAsTextFile to work on the cluster with the file:// protocol to work I have used the steps in the updated answer.

Comment: I understand the saveAsTextFile works well in HDFS but when running spark on windows without a cluster and I use saveAsTextFile("file:///Java/output"), why does it give me an error? How can I save file in my setup?

Comment: I am not using Windows, but Linux and I have HDFS. Sometimes it is easier to use some Cloud service, like Google DataProc which allows you to create single node clusters in just a couple of minutes. You get there a properly setup cluster. The drawback is that this costs money, but for a couple of minutes in a month the cost is really very low. I actually could also not figure out the error from the error stack trace. In your case the you are taking the right approach to save the file.